# redirecting http to https and www to non www on apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I need to set advanced (for me) redirect based (hopefully) on our apache2 and site .htaccess.
We want that anyone who will point www.example.com and example.com or https://www.example.com would have been redirected to https://example.com

The issue is that links after domain must work.
For example http://example.com/category/article/newest and https://www.example.com/category/article/newest would work after that redirection and pointing to correct https://example.com/category/article/newest

We tried redirection as you can see in attached .htaccess but problem is that it is for example redirecting http://www.example.com/category/article/newest to https://example.com/

our current .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteRule .* public/index.php
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development
<IfModule mod_php.c>
    php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off
    php_flag register_globals off
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your rules to:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

This way, if the request is not HTTPS *or* if the request starts with a "www", it will get redirected to HTTPS and without the "www".